# Cannot catkin_make example from Tutorials

Tags: ros, package.xml, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used my fresh knowledge from [package form format](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) to extend basics of catkins cmakelist.txt and package.xml
Is there anything principally wrong with it or is all right. It does work with catkin_make

I use this [CMakeLits and package.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAibjVrZ3pVemJBR3M/view?usp=sharing).txt. I would be glad if someone could have a look at it and tell if any mistakes in it

---

Edit: So i got the general order, but where to place this, it feels like deadlock: How to add when it needs to be exported?

```
add_library(my_test_lib ${MY_TEST_LIB_SRC})

catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS #catkin packages
        roscpp 
        std_msgs 
        #message_generation
    #DEPENDS Boost  #other libs
    #INCLUDE_DIRS include   #my headers
    LIBRARIES my_test_lib #my exported libs from the project
    #CFG_EXTRAS - Additional configuration options 
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225439/cannot-catkin_make-example-from-tutorials/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-31**:
Related: [How to move packages from build to devel folder](http://answers.ros.org/question/225447/how-to-move-packages-from-build-to-devel-folder/).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-31**:
Don't post answers if you're not answering your own question. If you want to update your question (to provide us with more information fi), then please use the *edit* button/link.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-31**:
re: deadlock: there is no deadlock. As the documentation states, just add all your `add_library(..)` and `add_executable(..)` statements *after* the `catkin_package(..)` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only obvious thing that I would warn you about is the ordering; see my answer to: http://answers.ros.org/question/225447/how-to-move-packages-from-build-to-devel-folder/

The ordering requirement is the last item on this page: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_overview.html and is also documented on the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0